# Omnifaces Escape JSON Strings

Tags: json, jsf, omnifaces

Is there a way to escape text for using in a json expression with Omnifaces:
e.g:

```
 "reviewBody": "#{of:escapeJS(reviewBean.text)}"
```

This appears to escape single quotes but I want to escape double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JSON encoding in EL, use [`#{of:toJson}`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/2.1/of/toJson.fn.html) instead (introduced in OmniFaces 1.5).

```
"reviewBody": #{of:toJson(reviewBean.text)}
```

Note that it already takes care of doublequotes. This function not only deals with `CharSequence` (`String` and friends), but also properly deals with `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, `Object[]`, `Collection`, `Map` and even true Javabeans. Basically, you can encode "everything" with it without worrying about the format and quoting. See also the [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Converters), [javadoc](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Json.html) and [source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Json.java).